# how to write value into cell with vba code without auto type conversion?

Tags: string, excel, vba, type-conversion

This problem seems very simple, yet I just can not find the solution (I am already loosing my mind about it :) )

OK, so I just want to put a certain value into an excel cell, using vba code, just as simple as this:

```
Cells(1,1).Value2 = "123,456"
```

The problem: this is a string (intentionally), but excel always convert it to number, and put that number into the cell, instead of the string that I wanted.

How can I force excel not to convert it, and just put into the cell exactly what I want (the string)??

Thanks,

Comment: Format the cell as Text before you write the value

Comment: Short answer: you can't.  The assignment logic must be customized based on the conversions you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 11):

```
Cells(1,1).Value2 = "'123,456"
```

note the single apostrophe before the number - this will signal to excel that whatever follows has to be interpreted as text.

Answer (score 9):

Indeed, just as commented by Tim Williams, the way to make it work is pre-formatting as text. Thus, to do it all via VBA, just do that:

```
Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
Cells(1, 1).Value = "1234,56"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the problem with them (Tim's answer too) is that those values that need to be put into the cells are not constants (not like "123,456"), but variables, and they are sometimes regular strings ("abc"), sometimes numbers, sometimes strings that contain number, sometimes even dates, ...  And more, I have to be able to compare later the original value of the variable, and the value that is in the cell, whether they are equal or not (and 12 not equal to "12", " '12" not equal to "12", etc.)  Isn't it possible just simply switch this automatic conversion off somehow?

Comment: This variable would be declared as Variant? Supposing you need to compare it later, but can't assume beforehand which type it is, you could first determine it programatically with the [VarType(var)](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_vartype.asp) function, and write a routine to deal with the comparison when types do not match. It could be used also to set the NumberFormat of a cell, depending on the variable type: If VarType(var) = 8 then Cells(1,1).NumberFormat = "@", If VarType(var) = 7 then Cells(1,1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" etc.

Comment: Yes, as Variant. But I do not need a complicated comparison routine, because it's completely OK that "1" is not equal with 1. The problem is that when I write "1" into the cell, and then compare it with "1", the result is false, because there is no "1" in the cell any more, but 1. (The other part of your suggestion is an applicable way around, it is just still unbelievable for me that there is no way to tell Excel not to auto-convert the content of the variable that you put into the cell. It is possible?? grrr. :) )

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late, but I had a similar problem with dates that I wanted entered into cells from a text variable. Inevitably, it converted my variable text value to a date. What I finally had to do was concatentate a ' to the string variable and then put it in the cell like this:

```
prvt_rng_WrkSht.Cells(prvt_rng_WrkSht.Rows.Count, cnst_int_Col_Start_Date).Formula = "'" & _ 
    param_cls_shift.Start_Date (string property of my class)
```